# React Type error: '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

React error given to JSX elements.
I got this error after bumping react version from 17 to 18.

Answer (score 1):

If you get this after [upgrading to React 18](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210), you must now change

```
export const MyFunctionComponent: React.FC = (props) => {...}
```

to

```
interface Props {
  children?: React.ReactNode
}
export const MyFunctionComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `@types/react@18.0.1`, `VFC` no longer exists and `FC` no longer implies a `children` property. You must manually define the prop as

```
type Props = {
  // props
  children?: React.ReactNode
}
// or
type Props = React.PropsWithChildren<{
  // props
}>

const Component: FC<Props> = props => {
  // ...
}
```